# Building my own drawer with ListView occurs tileWidth != leadingSize.width

Tags: flutter-web

I use ListView instead of Drawer and I want to make it collapsible, just like Dashboard style Drawer.

My solution is click a button, and setState the width of the SizedBox.

Somehow it spits out tileWidth != leadingSize.width

is there any solution to this error?

```
Widget _menu(bool isOpen) {  
      return SizedBox(
        width: isOpen ? 250 : 0,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("MENU"),
                ListTile(title:Text('item1')),
                ListTile(title:Text('item2')),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Change ListTile to simple Text widget won't cause any issue.

I am making a project on flutter web.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this Container inside ListTile

```
        ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              width: 64,
              // ..
            ),
            // ..
         );
```